# Angular/2: Filtering a JSON response with multiple defined properties

Tags: json, angular, typescript, properties, indexof

**UPDATE**

As [developer003 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43827264/1626716), I did this:

[image]

It works, but not at all. If I add an other property as *c.details.author* (string[]) or *c.details.index* (number), it doesn't work, and the function doesn't return nothing (error).

Here an extract of my JSON database:

```
[
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": "ad dolor ipsum quis",
    "details": {
      "author": ["Wallace Stephens", "Steve Ballmer"],
      "game": {
        "short": "tdp",
        "name": "Thief: The Dark Project"
      },
      "newdark": {
        "required": true,
        "version": "1.20"
      },
      "firstreleasedate": "2007/04/27",
      "lastupdatedate": "2017/01/28"
    }
  }
]
```

So I can look for another details properties than strings. Any idea?

---

**ORIGINAL POST**

[image]

I created a function which, when I call it as a (keyup) event, filters an HTML datatable when I type something in an input.

`return c.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.target.value.toLowerCase()) != -1;`

I want to be able to filter, not only by *name*, but also by *details.author*, *details.game.name*, *details.firstrelease*... etc.

How can I change `c.name` to apply these properties? Do I need to create a loop? Should I use *.map()*?

Comment: Hey, did my answer work for you?

Comment: @developer033 Not at all, please see my updated main post :)

Answer (score 2):

Right now I can think in 2 approaches:

**1st:**

º Create a `function` to *parse* `(toLowerCase())` the property value and handle if it contains the value or not:

```
containsVal(property, value) {
  return property.toLowerCase().indexOf(value) !== -1;
}

filterFunc(c) {
  return this.containsVal(c.name, VALUE_TO_SEARCH) ||
    c.details && (
      this.containsVal(c.details.author, VALUE_TO_SEARCH) ||
      this.containsVal(c.details.firstrelease, VALUE_TO_SEARCH) ||
      (c.details.game && this.containsVal(c.details.game.name, VALUE_TO_SEARCH))
    );
}
```

**2nd:**

º Map the only needed properties and filter them.

```
arr.map(item => {
  return {
    name: item.name,
    author_details: item.details && item.details.author, 
    firstrelease_details: item.details && item.details.firstrelease, 
    game_name: item.details && item.details.game && item.details.game.name
  };
}).filter(item => {
  return Object.keys(item).some(key => {
    const value = item[key];

    return value && value.toLowerCase().indexOf(VALUE_TO_SEARCH) !== -1;
  });
});
```

Comment: @developer003 It worked but not at all, please see my main updated post.